# Add custom android webview error page

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-webview, custom-error-pages

In my app i want an error activity **"NOT A ERROR HTML PAGE"**. Which contain refresh button and a layout. I have search for it but i found is just a custom html error page from assets folder.

I have created a some code which is below,
i want is that when ever network error occurs it will open an activity like this and user can easily refresh page using button.

> I want to make error page like this one..

[image: Error page with refresh button]

This is not a html error page. This contains layout with refresh button,

```
public WebView mWebview ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    mWebview  = new WebView(this);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {


            // Do Something Here,  I don't know what to do.. :(


        }
    });

    mWebview.loadUrl("google.com");
    setContentView(mWebview);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.refresh:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, CeS1.class));
            finish();
            return true;

        case R.id.about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Credits_activity.class));
            finish();
            return true;

        case R.id.gotomain:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: implement the onReceivedError() method shown in your code to implement something like startActivity(new Intent(this, error_activity.class)) and you can even send error information along as you start your error_activity.

Comment: Can you explain in detail??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call this in your code

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
 //place you error code here
   }
});
```

Comment: This `onReceivedError()` method has deprecated. refer this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout with 2 layers. One is `WebView`, another is your error layout. When your `WebView` encounters network error, you can hide your `WebView` and show errorView with retry button.

Answer (score 0):

first, you put your HTML error page on the asset folder, then 
You need override onReceivedError according to the following code,

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
.
.
.

   // api<23
   @Override
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String url) {
        view.stopLoading();
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error/error.html");
    }

  // api> 23
  @Override
  @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    view.stopLoading();
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error/error.html");
//          super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
  }
.
.
.

}
```